# default application like wget for windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp, dos

I remember there is some build-in application that I can use to download websites. but there is not wget in windows xp sp3.

What the name of the app?

I want to use it in my **BATCH application**.

Comment: thx for the close vote. I vote to close SO, because its off-topic. it should be about programming only. Scripts are for admins and business people(SQL is not for programmers).

Comment: This question belongs on superuser

Comment: @David Heffernan please also migrate SQL questions. Batch is more for programmers than SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is wget for windows and it works perfectly:

```
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
```

Comment: but I would like to NOT download some outside tool and my script to be portable between systems.

Comment: Yet, wget is just an exe file that needs no installation and could be included in your app.

Comment: `wget` is the answer; find a way to use it